# App deployed on Heroku crashes randomly

Tags: heroku

I'm hosting my app on Heroku, using JawsDB. Sometimes it runs normally, sometimes it crashes. Here's the logs:

```
2017-11-10T23:53:33.142649+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=1a43755b-a689-4ce2-939d-e71076d927ed fwd="108.28.184.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

It appears to me that there's no service from JawsDB and my app cannot connect to its database. I've read JawsDB documentation and my app still have the `connection url`, its `status` is `available`. I've also manually edited the `JAWSDB_URL` variable in my app's **settings**.

Any ideas what's going on with the app?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?

Comment: Yes I did. Since it's been a while, I believe I fixed it by adding a Procfile

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Procfile solved this problem.